# nifi processor ListAzureBlobStorage doesnt differentiate between file and folders

Tags: azure, azure-storage, apache-nifi

we are trying to migrate from ADLS gen1 to gen2 (hierarchical).

so we are changing processors, e.g. listHDFS is now ListAzureBlobStorage.

one issue I saw was, this new processor lists all files, and also directories.

this processor doesn't return any attribute, to differentiate b/w files and folders.

so I though of using "azure.length", as it is always "0" for folders (not documented, but I observed it)).

but if file is a 0kb files, then "routeonattribute" filters 0kb files too, thinking its a folder (my faulty logic".

I cannot be the first one who observed it. so do we have any workaround it? i am using NiFi 1.9.2.

(please refer image below). If i am running my polling logic at "aas_sync/load_status/depletion_global". I am getting 14 entries (13 files and 1 folder).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no folders in Azure Blob Storage.

There's a container, and inside of it, blobs. You can use the '/' to create "directories", but in the end, they will be just part of the blob name. Some clients are smart enough to parse and display it as folders, but don't be fooled, it's just the blob name.

[image]

Comment: updated my post. I am fine if we forget about files and folders nomenclature. my issue is, (if i take ur e.g.) i am getting img001.jpg and "pictures" in same list, and none of the attributes can clearly differentiate them. visually i can see, they are clearly different, :(

Comment: have you checked the write attributes https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-azure-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.azure.storage.ListAzureBlobStorage/ ? You can try azure.blobtype or mime.type